# Is there a way to solve this TypeError

Tags: python

I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. I need help.

```
next(fhr) # skip header row
customer_list = [] # initialize empty customer list

for line in fhr:
    ls = line.split(',')
    customer_list.append([ls[0], ls[1], ls[2], ls[3], ls[4], ls[5], ls[6], int(ls[7]), ls[8], ls[9], ls[10].strip('\n')])

from operator import itemgetter
customer_list.sort(key=itemgetter(7), reverse=True)
print(customer_list)

writepath = './loan-data-output-v1.csv'
fwh = open(writepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
fwh.write('Name' +','+ 'State' +','+'Age' +','+'Annual Income'+','+ 'Loan Type' +','+' Loan Amount' +','+ 'Length of Loan in Years' +','+ 'Days Delinquent' +','+ 'Interest Rate' +','+ 'Number of Loans Prior' +','+'Years as Customer' + '\n')

for i in customer_list:
    if customer_list[i][7] >= 90:
        fwh.write(customer_list[i][0] + ',' + customer_list[i][1] + ',' + customer_list[i][2] + ',' + customer_list[i][3] + ',' + customer_list[i][4] + ',' + customer_list[i][5] + ',' + customer_list[i][6] + ',' + customer_list[i][7] + ',' + customer_list[i][8] + ',' + customer_list[i][9] + ','+ customer_list[i][10] + '\n')
fhr.close()
fwh.close()
```

I am getting this error for the last for loop and I'm not sure what to do about it. Can someone help.
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/2970853

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: Maybe you can try: for i in range(len(customer_list)):

Comment: what is `customer_list`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using lists of lists so when you use `for i in list_of_list`, `i` itself becomes a list..

```
for i in customer_list:
    if i[7] >= '90':
        fwh.write(i[0] + ',' + i[1] + ',' + i[2] + ',' + i[3] + ',' + i[4] + ',' + i[5] + ',' + i[6] + ',' + str(i[7]) + ',' + i[8] + ',' + i[9] + ','+ i[10] + '\n')
fhr.close()
fwh.close()
```

Alternatively you can use,

```
for i in range(0,len(customer_list)):
    if customer_list[i][7] >= '90':
        fwh.write(customer_list[i][0] + ',' + customer_list[i][1] + ',' + customer_list[i][2] + ',' + customer_list[i][3] + ',' + customer_list[i][4] + ',' + customer_list[i][5] + ',' + customer_list[i][6] + ',' + str(customer_list[i][7]) + ',' + customer_list[i][8] + ',' + customer_list[i][9] + ','+ customer_list[i][10] + '\n')
fhr.close()
fwh.close()
```

EDIT: Second method assumes that your length of `customer_list` is constant or in other words you are not adding anything to `customer_list` during the loop. Thanks to `DanielRoseman` for pointing out potential bug in second code..

EDIT 2:
Thanks to `quamrana` for suggesting this way,

```
for i in customer_list:
    if i[7] >= '90':
        i[7] = str(i[7])
        fwh.write(','.join(i[0:11]) + '\n')
fhr.close()
fwh.close()
```

Comment: Don't recommend the second one. It's almost *never* the right thing to do in Python.

Comment: Why is it so, I am excited to see something new in python if it is so..:)

Comment: Because the first way is correct. Always iterate over the thing itself, not range of len of the thing.

Comment: But what makes you think iterating over len of the thing is incorrect? Are there any potential bugs or inefficiency?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think i got your point, ```len(thing)``` is only executed for one time and if we add something during loop into ```thing``` we can't iterate over newly added thing. I got it, Thanks for correcting me.:)

Comment: btw, when using `for i in customer_list:` the parameter to `fhw.write()` can now be `','.join(i[0:11]) + '\n'`.

Comment: Ya it can, I forget it totally Thanks @quamrana